# Redefining the item command of the description environment

Tags: description

My thesis contains many `description` environments. After showing it to my supervisor, he complained about the missing separation between the items titles and descriptions. I tried to redefine the `\item` command, to change all `description` environments at once, without changing every `\item` manually.

While my approach works for simple items (the first one), it fails for items that contain multiple paragraphs of text in the description (like the second one).

```
\documentclass{book}                                                                

\let\olddescription\description
\def\description{%
  \olddescription \let\olditem\item%
  \def\item[##1]##2{\olditem[##1]{\hfill \\##2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[The First Item]{This text describes the first item.}
\item[The Second Item]{This text describes the second item.
Contrary to the description of the first item, it is quite a bit longer.

Additionally, it consists of multiple paragraphs, which causes problems
with redefining the item command.}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

On compiling with pdflatex, the following error message appears:

```
Runaway argument?                           
{This text describes the second item. Contrary to the description of \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \item was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.14

?
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.15 ...roblems with redefining the item command.}

?
```

If I remove the second item, it works. Is there a way to fix my `\item` command?

---

I know that I can just redefine the `descriptionlabel` command like this:

```
\let\olddescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\olddescriptionlabel{#1:}}
```

But this does unfortunately not work for the line break I tried to add after the title using the code I found at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description.

Comment: What do you want to change? How should it look like?

Comment: Commands defined with `\def` are not allowed to have `\par` in the replacement text.  You need to use `\long\def` for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230316/3954), **egreg** has explained the problems with your current definition and a way to ammend it. However, I'd suggest you to use the `nextline` style for `desciption` offered by the `enumitem` package:

```
    \documentclass{book}                                                                
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{style=nextline}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[The First Item]
This text describes the first item.
\item[The Second Item]
This text describes the second item.
Contrary to the description of the first item, it is quite a bit longer.

Additionally, it consists of multiple paragraphs, and doesn't cause problems
since we didn't redefine the item command.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\LetLtxMacro` is not needed here.

Comment: While trying to get it done by changing the `\item` command I totally overlooked this option of enumitem -.-

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is faulty where you redefine `\item` with two arguments; the original `\item` has only one (at least for `description`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\description\expandafter{%
  \description \let\olditem\item
  \def\item[##1]{\olditem[##1]\mbox{}\\}}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[The First Item] This text describes the first item.
\item[The Second Item]This text describes the second item.
Contrary to the description of the first item, it is quite a bit longer.

Additionally, it consists of multiple paragraphs, which causes problems
with redefining the item command.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The braces you already have in your code will do nothing, so it's not really necessary to remove them.

[image]

Your code will work if you say `\long\def\item[##1]##2{...}` so as to allow for `\par` tokens in the second argument.

Of course the approach with `enumitem` is better.

Comment: I really like that solution, because it works without using yet another package. Unfortunately, it seams to break the `\blindlist` command of the blindtext package, that I use in some of the unfinished chapters, so I chose the solution of Gonzalo.