# Aligning linebreaks in long `\item{}` inside description environment

Tags: align, description

Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item{Foo\\ Bar \\ Baz }
        : Foo, Bar and Baz are friends.
    \item a, b, c
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

Linebreaks are working fine but `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` are not aligning to the left. Is there a way to fix this? I rather redefine the `description` environment rather than change the text inside `item{}` everywhere in my current doc which has many `description`s.

Answer (score 5):

Two observations. First, in LaTeX's `description` environment, the argument of `\item` should be encased in square brackets, not curly braces. Second, to place several items in the argument of `\item` [pun intended] in a vertical stack, you could use a `tabular` environment. The following example code provides short-hand macro called `\mystack` that simplifies the creation of a stack of items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mystack[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[\mystack{Foo \\ Bar \\ Baz}]: Foo, Bar, and Baz are friends.
    \item[a, b, c] \dots
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank @Mico. This is helpful. Is there a way to do this by redefining the `\item`? I rather add a redefinition at the top rather than change the doc at hundreds of places.

Comment: Currently I am using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230309/8087 i.e., `\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}`.

Comment: @Dilawar -- If I understand your document setup correctly, you have to input `\item[`, `Foo \\ Bar \\ Baz` -- I trust you don't *literally* work with these exact words in your real document ... -- and `]` by hand. Is it really that much more work to enter `\mystack{` and `}` as well? If it really is too burdensome to do so, please edit your posting and provide a more realistic example of stacked words, to give your readers a better sense of what exactly needs to (and what does not need to) be accomplished..

Comment: Ah, sorry about that @Mico. The document I am dealing with is a large manual that needs to be converted to rst/markdown.  Currently, the  doc has `\item{\texttt{foo}\n \texttt{bar}\n \texttt{baz}\n}` etc and a very complicated redefinition of `\texttt` and `\item` which I have to remove else pandoc couldn't work. When I remove some complicated macros the alignment breaks. I can write a plugin for pandoc which can insert some macros/redefinitions at the top of the doc before converting. Another option is to use `gawk/sed/regex` which I am trying to avoid. Thanks for your time.